# Load File (Function & Variable Value) from Child Theme

Tags: customization, child-theme

Is there a way to load a file (`copyright.php`) functions & variable's value into child theme's `functions.php`

I'm trying to pass the value in order to change the footer credit. I can do it if I included the code directly within `functions.php`, but I'm trying to exclude the code to a different file so that my client can change the variables value easily in the future without touching `functions.php`. Below are my codes but it's not working:

**copyright.php** (within Child Theme folder)

```
function display_company_url() {    
global $company_url;
$company_url = 'www.mycompany.com';
return $company_url;
}

function display_company_name() {   
global $company_name;
$company_name = 'MY COMPANY';
return $company_name;
}
```

**functions.php** (Child Theme)

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_assets' );)
function my_assets() {
wp_register_script( 'copyright', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/copyright.php' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'copyright' );   
}


// REMOVE AND MODIFIED PARENT'S FOOTER
add_action( 'init', 'remove_parent_footer', 10);
function remove_parent_footer() {
remove_action('parent_footer', 'parent_footer_credits', 8);


add_action('parent_footer', 'child_footer_credits', 8); 
function child_footer_credits() {
    ?>
        <div class="site-info col-md-6">
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( __( '/login', 'childtheme' ) ); ?>" rel="nofollow"> <?php echo "Copyright" ?></a> &copy; <?php echo date("Y"); ?>
            <?php echo get_bloginfo( 'name' ) . ". All rights reserved."; ?> <br> <?php echo "Powered by"; ?>
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url( __( display_company_url(), 'childtheme' ) ); ?>" rel="nofollow"><?php echo display_company_name(); ?></a>
        </div><!-- .site-info -->
    <?php
}

}
```

The footer credit should be showing:

Copyright © 2017 BLOGNAME. All rights reserved.
Powered by MY COMPANY

Comment: If you want your client can change copyright content in future easily then best option would be placing these contents in `dashboard -> Add pages` and call that page in footer.php. This way client can change contents most easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to use the [WordPress Customize API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API). There you can set as many fields as you want and all will be nicely shown in the theme's Customize menu.

```
<?php
/* New Section in Customize */
add_action( 'customize_register','new_customize_option');
function new_customize_option( $wp_customize ) {

    /* --------------REGISTERING NEW SECTION --------------- */


    $wp_customize->add_section( 'rewp_logo' , array(
    'title'      => __( 'Copywrite fields', 'textdomain' ),
    'priority'   => 260,
    ) );

    /* -------------- S E T T I N G S --------------- */


    /* Setting: Set a text field   */
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'rewp-text' , array(
    'default'     => 'Copywrite 2017',
    'capability'  => 'edit_theme_options',
    ) );

    /* -------------- C O N T R O L S --------------- */

    /* Control: Upload Background */
    /* Control: Set a link */
    $wp_customize->add_control( new WP_Customize_Control( $wp_customize, 'rewp-text', array(
    'label'     => __( 'Copywrite text', 'textdomain' ),
    'section'   => 'rewp_logo',
    'settings'  => 'rewp-text',
    'type'      => 'text',
    'priority'  => 1
    ) ) );

} ?>
```

Then you can use it like:

```
$mods = get_theme_mods();
echo $mods['rewp-text'];
```

The suggestion of @Rishabh will also work but mind that if this page gets deleted by accident then you will need to create a new one and edit the code again.

Comment: Thanks! It's working. Your suggestion solved my problem.